# (How) can I share a package on the main Scala Bazaar (scala-dev) with sbaz

Tags: scala, sbaz, scalacl

I'm trying to make a compiler plugin available publicly using [sbaz](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/93).

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.lexspoon.org/sbaz/tutorial.html) : I packaged my JAR, uploaded it to [some public location](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/sbaz/scalacl/) and ran :

```
sbaz share scalacl-compiler-plugin-1.0-20101005.advert
```

sbaz then told me my package was shared, which I seemed to confirm by running `sbaz available` locally and even `sbaz install scalacl-compiler-plugin` with success.

However, when running `sbaz available` from another computer, my package is not visible.

Did I miss something ? Do I need special rights to share on the scala-dev universe ? (and if so, how can I apply or create / use another universe ?)
Is there any kind of à-la-Maven local sbaz repository ?

Thanks for any pointers,

Cheers

**Edit (problem solved = no problem)**: Ok, I'm silly, I forgot to run sbaz update before running sbaz available or sbaz install ....

Fixed ! (thanks for your answer, Dylan !)

Comment: Does your other computer have the correct universe set for the scala project directory you're running sbaz in?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm silly, I forgot to run `sbaz update` before running `sbaz available` or `sbaz install ...`.

Fixed !
(thanks for your answer, Dylan !)